# Hacking laptop power button: Turn on laptop when AC's back (Asus F533 laptop)

Tags: power, laptop, server

My question is closely connected to this question: [Hacking laptop power button: Turn on laptop when AC's back](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145575/hacking-laptop-power-button-turn-on-laptop-when-acs-back)

I was in doubt to reopen the discussion there, or start a new one. I choose the latter.

- I want to use an old laptop (Asus) as a printerserver. (octoprint, etc.). I start my printworkshop up with some Hue switches (for heating, light, the printerserver) and when everything works I start up the printer(s) themself.
- Problem is that the laptop will not start up by itself when power comes backon. I have to push the button to start it.
- this is where I found the answer in question: [Hacking laptop power button: Turn on laptop when AC's back](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145575/hacking-laptop-power-button-turn-on-laptop-when-acs-back) and tried to get this working.
- No luck because of these issues:
- 1. Because of the battery (old but still functioning) the voltage on the power button doesn't change much on power down.
     NB: I tried to disconnect the battery, but then I need two pulses from the power button to get it to run. First push only start the charger, second push the server.
- 2. The voltage on the power button switch is 0 and needs an pulse up (+ 3-v volt) to get it running. (precisely the other way around as in the other thread).

What I found to work with (but I have not enough knowledge to get this designed). So I could need help there.

The charger input = 19.6 V. I can connect a resistor + capicitor there to get a delayed push.

When the green LEF (server running) is ON and also when OFF, the voltages on the led are 3-5 V. When the light is on, I only have the difference between the both sides (difference about 1 to 1.5 V). So I have no idea how to use this to discharge the capacitor.

To use the solution of the other thread, at least I have to go from NPN to PNP?
I have to find something else to discharge the capactitor. Maybe a second circuit with connected to ground, with longer timing to get it back to zero?

I hope I am not to confusing in my explanations, and hope some of you are willing to help me solve the puzzle.
PS If nothing helps, I think I will use 1 or 2 relays to get the same thing done.

Could this work?
[image: first sketch to find solution]

When the power comes on the plug (topleft) with 19 V,
This is divided to about 3-4 V. After some time the R4C2 circuit will trigger Q2
pulling up the midswitch to about 3 V -> laptop goes on
little later the R1C1 circuit will trigger Q1
this will discharge C2 and pull Q2 down to zero?
Q2 closes and the midswitch of the power button goes down to 0 V.

I did not calculate exactly (think it will need some trial and error anyway), but would this concept work?

Comment: Have you considered another option? Perhaps, Wake on LAN?

Comment: Similar question on SE Super User Site: https://superuser.com/questions/984934/i-want-my-pc-to-turn-on-automatically-when-power-is-connected

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yes, I did consider that, even hoped for a "wake on power", but both are not available. Also searched for "hidden options in bios". Also not available. 
That is why I want to use a (as simple as possible) circuit to get this done.

Comment: On some systems Wake on LAN works even if not offered in the BIOS. Did you try it?

Comment: I did not find any way to get Wake on LAN working. That is why I switched to "wake on power on", like every server has. 
Not available on the laptop. As written above, I think it should be able to do it whith a couple of components (as questioned above)

Comment: Oops. I already discovered first error myself. There should be resistor between R1 and C1 so the voltage stays high in the beginning in favor for circuit R4C2 
I will change the image.

Comment: Sadly I have to say, that this project died from a sudden death. Accidently connected some wires, and before I could react, smoke came out, and the laptop did not start anymore. Next journey to the recyle station. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an optocoupler your circuit can work with any special requirement of the start button context.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdBwO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At startup C1 and C2 are discharged and so the P-FET M1 is conducting and the N-FET M2 is off.

The capacitor voltages are rising and after some time, dominated by R2 and C2, the N-FET M2 also starts conducting. Now the coupler LED is on and the start signal becomes active. The LED current is set by R3.

Finally the voltage across C1 will be close to 19 V, which turns the P-FET M1 off. This turns off the LED and removes the start signal. The timing can be changed with R1.

When the supply V1 turns off, the capacitors can be discharged via D2 and D3 if needed.

The delay and width of the pulse highly depend on the threshold voltages of both MOSFETS. So this circuit is not ideal for a series production.

---

A simpler solution with a smaller configuration range for the pulse delay and width is this one. The start delay (R1, C1) is not independent from the pulse width (C2, R2). If the value of R1 is too high, either the gate threshold voltage will not be reached, or - if R2 is adjusted - the pulse width will be very long as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcauFX.png)</sup>

A BJT solution is also possible but uses large capacitors and has a long LED current decay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmLPfZ.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Jens, for your complete answer. Touches the biggest worry I have on connecting something directly between the power of the charger and the button. Galvanic separation is the best to have there. 
From the experience with the laptop, I know I need a delay from about 1 second or higher. And the pulse should not last longer then 3 seconds. 
Think your third solution, should be good enough for that.

Comment: Question: Your approach also makes that I also want to try this (just to learn a bit more): 1. check how the connection between the two circuits is now (measuring the voltage difference between the two circuits on the ground side and + sides. 2. Depending on that figure how to make your third circuit work without the optocoupler.

Comment: Somewhere in my workshop are a couple of optocouplers. Just need to find them ;-)